# Set time format 'HH:MM:SS ' for Materialize Clockpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I have added below library

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/timepicker/materialize.clockpicker.css"/>
<script src="assets/plugins/timepicker/materialize.clockpicker.js"></script>
```

With Jquery library .

**My input element is**

```
<input id="default_start_time" name="default_start_time" class="timepicker" type="time">
```

**Script Section**

```
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
        default: 'now',
        twelvehour: false, // change to 12 hour AM/PM clock from 24 hour
        donetext: 'OK',
        format:"HH:ii:SS",
        autoclose: false,
        vibrate: true 
    });
```

Also I have tried

```
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
        default: 'now',
        twelvehour: false, // change to 12 hour AM/PM clock from 24 hour
        donetext: 'OK',
        format:"HH:MM:SS",
        autoclose: false,
        vibrate: true 
    });
```

But Time-picker Allows returning **hour:min** format *(Like 08:10, 19:06)*

What is the issue ??

Comment: What I have to do ,If I want to use this library with second variation . It will be good for me if it will concat default second value like 08:10:00 or 19:06:00

Comment: change the js and css links to cdn and provide a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try some small workaround, use `step="1"`

`<input id="default_start_time" name="default_start_time" class="timepicker" type="time" step="1">`

But generally seconds are not supported by datetime inputs and pickatime, see http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/#formats and http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/#formatting-rules

It's probably a good idea to open an issue at https://github.com/chingyawhao/materialize-clockpicker

Comment: That means It is not possible??

Comment: Not with the pickatime implementation without any modifications.

Comment: do you have any library-info which provides seconds variation

Comment: @SurajKhanra see my updated answer. The step parameter should be enough I guee.

Answer (score 8):

Materialize clockpicker dosent support seconds, but you can get the desired result by adding a simple jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.timepicker').pickatime({
        default: 'now',
        twelvehour: false, // change to 12 hour AM/PM clock from 24 hour
        donetext: 'OK',
        format: "HH:ii:SS",
        autoclose: false,
        vibrate: true
    });
    // For adding seconds (00)
    $('.timepicker').on('change', function() {
        let receivedVal = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(receivedVal + ":00");
    });
});
```